# Should I write unit tests for child class' inherited behaviour?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Let's say I have a **Chart** class with **setDatasets()** method for which I have written unit tests.

```
class Chart {
  // constructor and instance properties
  setDatasets() {
    // some logic
  }
}
```

Now I have also **BarChart** class which is **Chart**'s child class:

```
class BarChart extends Chart {
  // just a constructor invoking super() with specific parameters
}
```

Obviously **BarChart** instances will "inherit" **setDatasets()** method from **Chart** class. My question is: should I also write unit tests for **setDatasets()** method in **BarChart**?

Comment: Is there a reason for not to do it? What would happen if `BarChart` implements a different `setDatasets()` in the future? I'm not an expert on test development but I guess the more you test, the better.

Comment: I'm, worried about code duplication - I would have exactly the same test code in multiple places. I could abstract this to a separate module (e.g. testSetDatasets()), but then I'm worried about code's clarity. I'm interested in how pros handle such problems.

Comment: Tests should be as simple and autonomous as possible. Given that, a certain amount of duplication is often accepted. There's a good discussion on [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189322/should-i-test-inherited-methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that would be overkill. A Test class for BarChart is supposed to test only the code introduced in BarChart.

In your case, you should only test that the BarChart object is created with the "specific parameters".

Last but not least, on the long run, it will be easier to maintain if your unit tests are isolated and precise.